# Pipreqs requirements.txt is not correct

Tags: python, package, requirements.txt

Hello I am having troubles with the `pipreqs` librairy in Python. It doesn't generate the correct `requirements.txt` file. I am using a Python Virtual Environment and the only packages I have installed are `pipreqs` and `selenium` with

```
pip install pipreqs
pip install selenium
```

Structure of the project:

```
MyProject
 |- test.py
```

And `test.py` has only one line:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
```

---

First when I do

```
pipreqs ./
```

I got the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3474: character maps to <undefined>`
which I managed to solve by using

```
pipreqs ./ --encoding=utf-8
```

---

But now the `requirements.txt` generated doesn't match my expectations. In my opinion, it should be equal to:

```
selenium==1.341.0
```

But it is equal to:

```
brotli==1.0.9
cryptography==3.2.1
ipaddr==2.2.0
lxml==4.6.1
mock==4.0.2
ordereddict==1.1
protobuf==3.13.0
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
simplejson==3.17.2
```

---

Now when I try to clone this code and do `pip install -r requirements.txt` it doesn't install `selenium` and the code doesn't run.

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the issue I had was that my actual workspace was:

```
MyProject
 |- .venv   // <- My Python Virtual Environment
 |- test.py
```

My Python Virtual Environment was in my Project folder so when I run the command

```
pipreqs ./
```

it is looking at all the dependencies of all the files in the folder (including my virtual environment) and that is why it was generating a weird `requirements.txt` file.

To fix this, I used the option `--ignore` of pipreqs:

```
pipreqs ./ --ignore .venv
```

And the generated `requirements.txt` is:

```
selenium==3.141.0
```

You may also want to ignore other folders that are causing issues like this:

```
pipreqs --ignore bin,etc,include,lib,lib64,.venv
```

The --force tag will also overwrite the existing requirements.txt